# Headless install (and rename) of application

Tags: macos-sonoma

I have a script (that used to work, pre-Sonoma) to install an application from the command line while renaming it:

```
#!/bin/bash

BETA="https://www.zotero.org/download/client/dl?platform=mac&channel=beta"

rm -f zotero-beta.dmg
curl -L -o zotero-beta.dmg "$BETA"
hdiutil attach zotero-beta.dmg
rm -rf /Applications/Zotero-beta.app
cp -r /Volumes/Zotero/Zotero.app /Applications/Zotero-beta.app
hdiutil detach /Volumes/Zotero
```

this still appears to work, but when I start this application, it is immediately killed after starting. I can still open the DMG, drag the app to my downloads folder, rename it there, and drag it into Applications, and have the app work, so it's not the app itself that causes the kill.